# How to display rows where is more than 2 values in column in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

```
col1
-------
John One
John Kole Ole
Mike Robe Gut
Michael Spark
```

How can I display only these values from column in above DataFrame, which have more than 2 values, so or example to display only John Kole Ole and Mike Robe Gut, because these values have more than 2 words?

How to do that in Python Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
mask=df['col1'].str.split(' ').str.len().gt(2)
```

**OR**

```
mask=df['col1'].str.count(' ').ge(2)
```

Finally pass that mask:

```
out=df[mask]
#OR
print(df[mask])
```